# RNN model with one-hot encoding data for binary classification in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, sequence

I have the video stream on top of which I run the Amazon Rekognition on second frames. Rekognition outputs the probability of the 2000 classes (wood, zebra, fence, car, etc.).
I need to develop my classifier for 3 classes on top of these predictions.
So, for a video with a length of 1600 seconds, I have a 1600x2002 dataset (Rekognition classes, time offset videos, and a label of my class). I came up with the idea to capture the context of Rekognition classes.

I tried to make a simple RNN model but the loss seems weird It seems that he was mistaken somewhere in the dataset preparation

I create a separate dataframe, where I put the ohe-hot array into the column.

```
df_for_torch = pd.DataFrame(columns=['inputs', 'label'])
df_for_torch['label'] = df['label']
df_for_torch['inputs'] = df[input_labels].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0).values.tolist()
df_for_torch.to_csv(root_path+'data_torch.csv')
```

Then I load it through torchtext

```
tv_datafields = [("label", LABEL), ("inputs", TEXT)]
train = data.TabularDataset.splits(
               path=root_path, 
               train='data_torch.csv',
               format='csv',
               skip_header=True,
               fields=tv_datafields)[0]
```

Create train и valid

```
SEED = 18
train_data, valid_data = train.split(random_state = random.seed(SEED))
```

Batching

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
train_iterator, valid_iterator = data.BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data), 
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    sort=False,
    device = device)
```

Create vocab

```
TEXT.build_vocab(train_data, max_size = MAX_VOCAB_SIZE)
LABEL.build_vocab(train_data)
```

Build a model

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, embedding_dim)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
    def forward(self, input_labels):
        #input_labels = [sent len, batch size]
        embedded = self.embedding(input_labels)
        #embedded = [sent len, batch size, emb dim]
        output, hidden = self.rnn(embedded)
        #output = [sent len, batch size, hid dim]
        #hidden = [1, batch size, hid dim]
        assert torch.equal(output[-1,:,:], hidden.squeeze(0))
        return self.fc(hidden.squeeze(0))
```

Init it

```
INPUT_DIM = len(input_labels)
EMBEDDING_DIM = 500
HIDDEN_DIM = 256
OUTPUT_DIM = 1
model = RNN(INPUT_DIM, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
model = model.to(device)
criterion = criterion.to(device)
```

Train and eval methods

```
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion):
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    model.train()
    for batch in iterator:
        optimizer.zero_grad()       
        predictions = model(batch.inputs).squeeze(1)
        loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
        acc = binary_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion):    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in iterator:
            predictions = model(batch.inputs).squeeze(1)
            loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
            acc = binary_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_acc += acc.item()
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

Run everything

```
N_EPOCHS = 20
best_valid_loss = float('inf')
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    start_time = time.time()
    train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion)
    valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion)
    end_time = time.time()
    epoch_mins, epoch_secs = epoch_time(start_time, end_time)
    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'tut1-model.pt')
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Epoch Time: {epoch_mins}m {epoch_secs}s')
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
    print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')
```

But loss seems strange

```
Epoch: 01 | Epoch Time: 1m 43s
    Train Loss: -2230969.595 | Train Acc: 0.06%
     Val. Loss: 5658.502 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
Epoch: 02 | Epoch Time: 1m 36s
    Train Loss: -7322002.296 | Train Acc: 0.06%
     Val. Loss: 11616.960 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
....
```